# Nuxt: Dynamic head / meta title is undefined on ssr

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, meta-tags

I have a nuxt project, where the meta title and description comes (from nuxt/content).
The async fetch for the data is made in index and received in a sub component via a getter.

On generate, the meta tags are there but on ssr not :/

I tried it with async and await, but I still get the error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: seoTitle is undefined

(I tried it with a useless await this.getArticle const, in hope that the whole thing waits, this stuff is there, but no)

Here my code:

```
 async head() {
    const article = await this.getArticle
    const seoTitle = await this.getArticle.seoTitle,
      title = await this.getArticle.title,
      seoDescription = await this.getArticle.description

    return {
      title: `"${
        seoTitle.length ? seoTitle : title
      }"`,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: `${
            seoDescription.length
              ? seoDescription.slice(0, 50)
              : seoDescription.slice(0, 50)
          }`,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass why would it not? I don't use them neither and ESlint does it job perfectly. Also, what do you mean by `On generate, the meta tags are there but on ssr not`. You do have `target: static` and `ssr: true`, right? How can they be there on generate?

Comment: Yeah, thanks.

I might have not expressed it detailed enough. Actually it happens in dev mode.
I get data already wih asyncDate.
When I export it into static files (via generate --modern) it adds the meta tags correctly.

So that is fine.
But I am wondering how to archive that in ssr mode? Or will it just work, once I run build?
And if not, how to have conditional meta tags, like I want to have them by:
seoTitle.length ? seoTitle : title

Comment: My first question is still valid. Also, try building your app locally to debug this.

Comment: Yes @kissu target is statis, ssr is not at all in the config file.
(Currently the project is supposed to be static only. But my next project wont be)

Comment: `ssr: true` is the default and with `target: static`, you should be good. Does it work when you're `yarn generate` + `yarn start`, do you see your meta?

Comment: Hi @kissu, yes that works, but that was my initial setting ("On generate, the meta tags ..."). I just wonder, how I would that work, if it would not be a static app.

Comment: With my solution and `target: server`, it should work as well IMO. Just remember to `yarn build` + `yarn start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot use `async` on `head` because it is usually using some static values.

And looking at this [github answer](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1086#issuecomment-315398826), it looks like you can use `asyncData` to have access to the values you want to input in `head`.

```js
head() {
  return { title: this.info.title }
},
async asyncData ({ params }) {
  return axios.get(`/post/${params.id}/info`)
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        info: res.data.info
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
  })
},
```

Comment: if the above doesn’t work out check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328833/how-to-set-nuxt-ssr-async-metadata-in-a-typescript-class-component-fetching-usi/70328834#70328834