# Meta Tags not displayed on view source page using nuxtJs

Tags: nuxt.js

It's working fine in inspect element but not showing any meta tags in page view source .

```
 head: {
    title: "kutumbh",
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "Welcome to iMeWeUs,Login To Your Account To Make Memories" },

      {
        hid: 'twitter:card',
        name: 'twitter:card',
        content: 'summary_large_image'
      },
      { hid: 'twitter:site', name: 'twitter:site', content: '@nuxt_js' },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:url',
        name: 'twitter:url',
        content: 'link of our application'
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:title',
        name: 'twitter:title',
        content: 'iMeWeUs'
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:description',
        name: 'twitter:description',
        content:
          'Welcome to iMeWeUs,Login To Your Account To Make Memories'
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:image',
        name: 'twitter:image',
        content: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/logo-of-a-green-life-tree-with-roots-and-leaves-vector-illustration-vector-id1130887322?k=6&m=1130887322&s=612x612&w=0&h=wFft0N9UT93zLSNOlKhnp6dorAA_wsyS931R6M4jJ68='
      },
       // Open Graph
      // Test on: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
      { hid: 'og:site_name', property: 'og:site_name', content: 'iMeWeUs' },
      { hid: 'og:type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
      {
        hid: 'og:url',
        property: 'og:url',
        content: 'link of our application'
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:title',
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'iMeWeUs'
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:description',
        property: 'og:description',
        content:
          'Welcome to iMeWeUs,Login To Your Account To Make Memories'
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:image',
        property: 'og:image',
        content: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/logo-of-a-green-life-tree-with-roots-and-leaves-vector-illustration-vector-id1130887322?k=6&m=1130887322&s=612x612&w=0&h=wFft0N9UT93zLSNOlKhnp6dorAA_wsyS931R6M4jJ68='
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:image:secure_url',
        property: 'og:image:secure_url',
        content: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/logo-of-a-green-life-tree-with-roots-and-leaves-vector-illustration-vector-id1130887322?k=6&m=1130887322&s=612x612&w=0&h=wFft0N9UT93zLSNOlKhnp6dorAA_wsyS931R6M4jJ68='
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:image:alt',
        property: 'og:image:alt',
        content: 'iMeWeUs'
      }

    ],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet prefetch",
        href: "https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.2.9/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css"
      },
      {
        hid: 'canonical',
        rel: 'canonical',
        href: `our application link`
      }
```

mystories.vue

```
 head() {
    return {
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'twitter:title',
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: this.title
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:description',
          name: 'twitter:description',
          content: this.description
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:image',
          name: 'twitter:image',
          content: this.image
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:image:alt',
          name: 'twitter:image:alt',
          content: this.title
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          property: 'og:title',
          content: this.title
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:description',
          property: 'og:description',
          content: this.description
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          property: 'og:image',
          content: this.image
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image:secure_url',
          property: 'og:image:secure_url',
          content: this.image
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image:alt',
          property: 'og:image:alt',
          content: this.title
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please share some code. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also does this page helps you ? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo

Comment: Hi, can you share your `nuxt.config.js` file? And some code? You either don't have `ssr: true` or not using the SEO keys properly.

Comment: hey i just refer the nuxt documention,https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo....i try to do it only differnce is that on that specific page i used my dynamic contents which i recived from api

Comment: It looks like you need to use `asyncData` to prepopulate the `content`. Check my answer here and tell me if this one do work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67633638/8816585

Comment: hey hii,,i going through ur solution and also used asyncData but after i used as this.post.title on my  head() it won't help me yet

Comment: Please share relevant parts of your code, list only 2/3 of your SEO entries. Also, can you show us your `nuxt.config.js` file? Do you have `ssr: true` there? And yeah, inspecting the DOM is not relevant at all, you need to have it in your source code at first. Try to hardcode it there and see if it is present. Then, we will see to make it dynamic.

Comment: async asyncData({ params, $axios }) {
      const post = await $axios.$get(process.env.BASE_URL + "/api/"+`${atob(params.s)}`);
      console.log("*****",post);
      return { post }
    },
  head() {
    return {
  meta: [
        {
          hid: 'twitter:title',
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: this.post.title
        },
}
}

Comment: i added nuxt.config file in description of problem could u check it please

Comment: Hehe, could you please not post this in the comments but edit your question?

Comment: Also, could you add other parts as asked above?

Comment: yes yes i added there

Comment: The **whole** configuration file please. As shown here, it is quite various in terms of keys: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config#nuxtconfigjs

Comment: hey,when did u have time,i will peronally share my screen and then u will recommend me solution

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to go on a 1:1 session. I do offer this as a paid service tho: https://github.com/sponsors/kissu?frequency=one-time But feel free to provide the needed code and try to explain it here, it will be a pleasure to help for free.

Comment: okay..thanks dude..